# Select into not working for stored proceedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on a stored procedure to log in users and I need to return the player id. The provided name and password are correct when I test it, result returns 1 but playerID stays NULL

```
`player_login` (
username TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8,
txtPassword TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8,
OUT playerID INTEGER,
OUT result INTEGER
)
BEGIN
DECLARE password TEXT DEFAULT player_hash_password(txtPassword);
DECLARE num INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT PlayerID INTO playerID
    FROM players
    WHERE (LOWER(players.PlayerName)=LOWER(username) OR  LOWER(players.PlayerEmail)=LOWER(username))
    AND players.PlayerPassword = password
    LIMIT 1;
...
```

Why is the PlayerID not selected into playerID? PlayerID is a not null auto increment integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter matches the column name, a perennial problem with MySQL stored procedures.  Use a prefix for the parameters, something like:

```
`player_login` (
p_username TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8,
p_txtPassword TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8,
OUT p_playerID INTEGER,
OUT p_result INTEGER
)
BEGIN
DECLARE p_password TEXT DEFAULT player_hash_password(p_txtPassword);
DECLARE num INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT p_PlayerID = playerID
    FROM players p
    WHERE (LOWER(p.PlayerName)=LOWER(p_username) OR  LOWER(p.PlayerEmail)=LOWER(p_username))
    AND p.PlayerPassword = p_password
    LIMIT 1;
.
```